# 3D - surface area, 2D - perimeter, 1D - ?? (how do you call the equivalent term)

Tags: terminology

The other day I was thinking (while grinding some sugar to make it easier to dissolve in water):

When you 'cut' a **3D** object in multiple 3D objects:

- the total **volume** remains the same
- but the total **surface** area increases;

When you 'cut' a **2D** object in multiple 2D objects:

- the total **area** remains the same;
- but the total **perimeter** increases;

When you 'cut' a **1D** object in multiple 1D objects:

- the total **length** remains the same;
- but the total **?????** increases;

What is the **'?????'** called? Obviously it is just the **number of 'end points'** of the lines (the 1D objects). But is there an actual term for this? It would be the equivalent of perimeter in 2D or surface area in 3D.

Comment: I think number of end point is quite ok. In that dimension you usually consider only counting measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a fancy mathematical term, you can say the *$0$-dimensional Hausdorff measure*.  Which is the same as the counting measure, also known as the number of elements the set contains.